# Kafka Utils wrong classpath: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm attempting to make a very simple Kafka Producer and am currently following the [producer example](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+Producer+Example) except my producer does not have a partitioner class.

After exporting required files into a jar I transfer them to my Linux image and try to run it.

I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$$anonfun$parseBrokerList$1.apply(ClientUtils.scala:103)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$$anonfun$parseBrokerList$1.apply(ClientUtils.scala:102)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:44)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:194)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.map(ArrayBuffer.scala:44)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.parseBrokerList(ClientUtils.scala:102)
    at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.<init>(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:32)
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.<init>(DefaultEventHandler.scala:41)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.<init>(Producer.scala:60)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.<init>(Producer.scala:26)
    at producers.HelloWorldProducer.main(HelloWorldProducer.java:20)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 19 more
```

After looking at the kafka jar I see that the `utils` is its own package now and not located within `common`.

What would be the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer ended up being real silly ... I needed to use the `kafka-clients-0.8.2.0.jar` instead.